# python - django - adding multiple objects to dict in one line

Tags: python, django

I initialize a dict and add objects into it like this, so that at the end of day, i can render `data` to template

```
data = {}
data['one'] = "1"
data['two'] = "2"
data['three'] = "3"
...
...
```

but, is there a one-line solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what are the objects you're storing in the dict but for this particular case you could do:

```
data = {"one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3"}
```

or you could use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
data = dict(zip(["one", "two", "three"], [1,2,3]))
```

I think this last one is more pythonic and can be applied to any lists or generators.

If your two lists are not of the same length and you want to have default value you can check [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Answer (score 2):

```
data = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
```

or

```
data = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```